# Clarifying the [windows] and [linux] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-excerpt

Could we get a better tag excerpt for [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) and [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux)? They sound overly strict and negative.

[windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) is

> Windows is a family of client, server, and mobile operating systems, developed by Microsoft. If your question has nothing to do with Windows APIs or Windows-specific behaviour then do not use this tag, even if you are running on Windows.

[linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) is

> For questions that are specific to the GNU/Linux operating system. If your question has nothing to do with Linux APIs or Linux-specific behavior you should not use this tag, even if you are running on Linux.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it could be phrased more positively with something like this:

[windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows)

> Windows is a family of client, server, and mobile operating systems, developed by Microsoft. Use this tag only if your question relates to using Windows APIs or Windows-specific behavior. Questions relating to using or troubleshooting Windows are off topic.

[linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux)

> GNU/Linux, commonly shortened as Linux, is an open source operating system. Use this tag only if your question relates to using Linux APIs or Linux-specific behavior. Questions relating to using or troubleshooting Linux are off topic.

Comment: Just used this as a great example of wiki excerpt actually explaining tag usage and not being a copypaste from Wikipedia.